# How load QImage from path?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qimage

I captured an Image with camera in my qt quick application.I want to send the path to my c++ code and load that Image in c++ `QImage`.But the Path is `image://camera/preview_1` and I don't know How work with that path?

```
Camera {
    id: camera

    imageCapture {
        onImageCaptured: {
            console.log("Preview = "+preview);
            photoPreview.source = preview
            console.log("CapturedImagePath => "+camera.imageCapture.capturedImagePath);
            up.loadImage(preview);
        }
}
```

**c++ class**

```
void UserProfile::loadImage(QString path)
{    
    QUrl imageUrl(path);
    qWarning()<<"imageUrl.host()=>"<<imageUrl.host();
    qWarning()<<"imageUrl.path()=>"<<imageUrl.path();
    qWarning()<<"imageUrl.toLocalFile()=>"<<imageUrl.toLocalFile();
    bool isOpend= m_image.load(path); //m_image is an QImage object
    qWarning()<<"Image loaded=> "<<isOpend;
}
```

**Application output**

```
D MyApp: qml: Preview = image://camera/preview_1
D MyApp: qml: CapturedImagePath =>
W MyApp: imageUrl.host()=> "camera"
W MyApp: imageUrl.path()=> "/preview_1"
W MyApp: imageUrl.toLocalFile()=> ""
W MyApp: Image loaded=> false
```

Comment: I suspect you really want [captureToLocation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html#captureToLocation-method) and the [imageSaved](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html#imageSaved-signal) event

Comment: @selbie I seaid in [my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117481/camera-not-saving-the-captured-image).the imageSaved event don't work

Comment: It's not common practice for someone answering your question to know what you've asked before.  Every question you ask needs to be complete with all relevant information.  Basically, we need [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL `image://camera/preview_1` means that the image data is living in a [QQuickImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) instance. Probably, it's a [QQuickImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) instance created by `Camera`.

As the `UserProfile` instance is living in the same QQmlEngine as the `camera` lives, you can

```
void UserProfile::loadImage(const QString &path)
{
    auto myQmlEngine = qmlEngine(this);
    if(myQmlEngine==nullptr)
        return;

    QUrl imageUrl(path);
    auto provider = reinterpret_cast<QQuickImageProvider*>( myQmlEngine->imageProvider(imageUrl.host()));

    if (provider->imageType()==QQuickImageProvider::Image){
        QImage img = provider->requestImage(imageUrl.path().remove(0,1),nullptr,QSize());
        // do whatever you want with the image
    } 
}
```

Be careful with the `reinterpret_cast`. You also have to make sure that the [QQuickImageProvider::imageType()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html#imageType) is returning [QQmlImageProviderBase::Image](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlimageproviderbase.html#ImageType-enum).

***and you could also use `capturedImagePath` instead of the `preview` URL*** to prevent this complexity if it could be an option for your usecase.

Comment: your answer worked,but after chaning `imageUrl.host().remove(0,1)` to `imageUrl.path().remove(0,1)`